# Would a french drain solve my water issues?

Tags: drainage

My yard slopes toward my house. The foundation is 2 to 3 feet below the yard. I have water that seeps into the crawl space after large rains. Would a linear french drain 6 to 8 ft. out from the house work?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an area to drain the water two that is lower than your crawl space a French drain will work great.
I have seen folks put them in with the drain point higher than the low area they were trying to keep dry.
In some cases if natural drainage is not available a small pit in the drain can be pumped to the storm runoff, this is requires in some areas to prevent standing water under the house.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I worked for a waterproofing subcontractor and in almost every situation where the homeowner had a leaky basement area, in addition to digging out and waterproofing the foundation, we would install a french drain, usually right next to the wall. I tried to do this myself, however, my house was built on a rockledge with approximately 4" of filldirt atop the rock. Said rock was its own french drain, so to say. That's one of the only exceptions. Also, be sure to get the drain sock to save yourself a lot of hassle and headache later on.